# Loading 2 arrays into one object PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I currently have code like this twice, one for each table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Characters";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    
    $dataset = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $dataset[]=$row;
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

This works, and I get 2 separate arrays from 2 separate tables. I want to know how to put both of these PHP arrays into an object like you see in JSON. The nodes array from one table, and the links array from the other table.

```
{
 "nodes": [
    {"name": "Bob", "group": 1},
    {"name": "Bill", "group": 2}
 ],
 "links": [
    {"source": "Bill", "target": "Bob", "value": 1}
 ]
}
```

I've seen solutions that merge both arrays, but I need them to stay **separated** and I need both arrays to be in the **same object**. If there isn't a way to do this in PHP, is there a way I can send both PHP arrays to Javascript and then combined them in an object there? Thanks

Comment: You just need to put both arrays in a single associative array, which is converted to json at the end.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the results of each query in separate arrays, for instance `$nodes` and `$links`. Then you can combine them with:

```
$results = ["nodes" => $nodes, "links" => $links];
echo json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

As simply as

```php
$result = [
    'nodes' => $array1,
    'links' => $array2,
];

$jsonResult = json_encode($result);
```